# Trouble in installing 3rd party software in ubuntu 16.10

Tags: system-installation, package-management, software-installation, updates, ubuntu-gnome

trouble to install 3rd party software in ubuntu 16.10. I recently download the Teamviewer .deb file and try to install through package installer ... it denied to install ... I don't know why ... and second thing is that while update the software it suggest to off the 3rd party software .

Comment: My crystal ball tells me the package you tried to install had unmet dependencies, but it would be better if you provided the error messages you got.

Comment: Make sure you get the multiarch deb file, and **not** the 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Well known TeamViewer dependency issues.

Go with:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32asound2 lib32z1 ia32-libs
```

Then try to install .deb file

`sudo dpkg -i team[Press TAB-KEY].deb`

If this doesn't work for you, paste the output.